# Is Google AMP available for google.com.au searches?

Tags: amp-html

When searching for google AMP articles in google.com.au (e.g. "The Guardian") all articles shown are not linked to the AMP version.

When searching google.co.uk, the same articles link to the Guardian amp versions.

So my question is, Is a Google AMP article version reliant here in Australia?

Comment: possible duplicate of [AMP-html page not displaying as intended in Google Search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36218539/amp-html-page-not-displaying-as-intended-in-google-search?rq=1), you might want to check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36237150/5995040).

Answer (score 0):

Yes as of the beginning of September. Here is the article:

http://www.castleford.com.au/blog/2016/hey-australia-faster-page-loads-are-here-as-googles-amp-arrives-down-under

Google AMP pages don't get generated automatically, you have to build them out and Google will server them if you have set up your standard web page with the correct head tag link canonical to your AMP page.

There are a lot of restrictions with AMP pages so if it's something you plan to incorporate into your site, read everything you can before even attempting to begin. This is a great 3rd party article written on creating great AMP pages. [Turn your AMP page up to 11](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/02/everything-about-google-accelerated-mobile-pages/%22Turn%20your%20AMP%20up%20to%2011%22).