# My website AMP pages doesn't appear in google search though they are indexed and no errors appear in the search console. Why?

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, amp-html

I am using Automattic AMP plugin for my WordPress site and its doing very well as no AMP page errors appear in search console after indexation. The problem is that my AMP pages doesn't appear in top carousel in google search. Why does this happen? Please anyone try to post a relevant answer.

Comment: hi, if there are no validation errors in your amp markup, then google bot hasn't yet indexed your amp pages, the amp pages are cached at google's cdn and displayed in search results,wait and check in google search console.read more at : https://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-search-console-amp-pages/157771/

Comment: Thanks Allen for your reply. But, my AMP pages have been indexed as mentioned in my search console and there are no errors. Why my posts still doesn't appear in the google search?

Comment: I hope you are trying to search with mobile device, and is your site ranking for given keyword, and is the rich snippet type of news.

Comment: My site isn't included in google search. Is that the reason?

Comment: possible duplicate of [AMP-html page not displaying as intended in Google Search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36218539/amp-html-page-not-displaying-as-intended-in-google-search?rq=1), you might want to check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36237150/5995040).