# Show Image instead of Website's title

Tags: html, wordpress, amp-html

we installed the AMP Plugin https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/amp/ some days ago in order to boost mobile visiting of out Website.

Though the installation itself worked good and we could also adjust the appeareance of how articles are displayed in AMP we are still facing one problem: We can not get a header image instead of the pages title to work in search results.

Please see [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfP4S.png) for this.

The website we are trying to accomplish this is tichyseinblick.de

Can you give us any advice on this?
Best Regards
Fabian

Comment: You can check this [tutorial](https://www.keycdn.com/blog/accelerated-mobile-pages/). It discusses on how to show image on search results that appears in the carousel. Also, as stated in this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36218539/amp-html-page-not-displaying-as-intended-in-google-search), the use of AMP pages is limited at present. Google search results for example will not display the AMP equivalent instead of your page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Logo](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/articles) 600x60 px in the Rich Snippet.